# Test method to validate Regex not working with global variables but working with local variables in Javscript

Tags: javascript, regex, global-variables

I'm trying to solve this problem since couple of hours but I'm not succeeding. I'm a beginner at programming so please excuse me if i made a dumb mistake. Thanks a lot.

The following code doesn't work when username and password are declared globally.

```
const form = document.querySelector ('.form');
const feedback = document.querySelector ('.feedback');
const patternPassword = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$/;
const patternUsername = /^[a-zA-Z]{5,15}$/;

const username = form.username.value;
const password = form.pass.value;

form.addEventListener ('submit', (e) =>{
    
    e.preventDefault();
    if (patternUsername.test (username) && (patternPassword.test (password)))  {
        feedback.textContent = 'Congrats! You Have signed up.';
    } else {
        feedback.textContent = 'Wrong details.';
    }   
});
```

But when i declare username and password locally like below. They do work. But I need to declare them globally because i need to use them somewhere else.

```
const form = document.querySelector ('.form');
const feedback = document.querySelector ('.feedback');
const patternPassword = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$/;
const patternUsername = /^[a-zA-Z]{5,15}$/;

form.addEventListener ('submit', (e) =>{
    const username = form.username.value;
    const password = form.pass.value;
    e.preventDefault();
    if (patternUsername.test (username) && (patternPassword.test (password)))  {
        feedback.textContent = 'Congrats! You Have signed up.';
    } else {
        feedback.textContent = 'Wrong details.';
    }
});
```

Also, if i don't use the variables and just reference the inputs like 'form.username.input' in the regex test method, it works that way too.

```
const form = document.querySelector ('.form');
const feedback = document.querySelector ('.feedback');
const patternPassword = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$/;
const patternUsername = /^[a-zA-Z]{5,15}$/;

form.addEventListener ('submit', (e) =>{
 
    e.preventDefault();
    if (patternUsername.test (form.username.value) && (patternPassword.test (form.pass.value)))  {
        feedback.textContent = 'Congrats! You Have signed up.';
    } else {
        feedback.textContent = 'Wrong details.';
    }
});
```

Any help would be really appreciated because this problem is making me crazy.

Comment: The values to the global variables are read when the page loads, at that time the inputs are empty. That's why you need to read the values in the event listener. You can declare a function, which reads the values, then call that function whenever you need password and username.

Comment: @teemu Thanks a lot for your time and reply. I do not understand your answer. I have learned that global variables should work everywhere but why it's not working in my case? Also, if i dont use the variables and just reference the inputs like  'form.username.input' in the regex test method, it works that way too.

Comment: When the page loads `form.username.value` is an empty string so `username` stays empty when used inside the event listener. However if you fetch `form.username.value` upon submission then you get the most recent value for the text box.

Comment: `form.username.value` returns a _value_, not a reference, and you're reading that value from an empty input element. The value stays in the variable as long as the value of the variable is explicitly changed.

Comment: Welcome. May be `regex` tag is not necessary here.

Comment: @crossishere He means that the value for those variables is defined at the very beginning of your application in the first case. In the second case, instead, you are defining the value everytime that the event is triggered

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I understand it now. Have a good day. Also, I'm new to this site so i don't know how to mark this problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I wanna mark this problem as solved and I read somewhere to post an answer yourself and mark it solved.

Below is the solution to the problem as @teemu mentioned.

> The values to the global variables are read when the page loads, at that time the inputs are empty. That's why you need to read the values in the event listener. You can declare a function, which reads the values, then call that function whenever you need password and username.

Edit: RIP, it says you'll be able to accept the answer in 2 days.